# Table View with two "columns"?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm really new to Xcode and Objective C but I can't seem to find a tutorial on a simple table I'd like to create.  I'd like to have a table (grouped style) with only three rows but two columns.  Column A would have a label (like 'Name:') and column B would have the actual data ("Jason").

I can't seem to find how to do this.  Unless I'm just completely looking up the wrong thing?  Was hoping someone could help me on how to do this or point me in the right direction.

Thank you!!

Comment: since you are new to iOS I would recommend to watch the great CS193P course videos from Stanford on Itunes U http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=384233225

Answer (score 7):

You don't want to use a table with 2 columns. They are not used in iOS.
You should use a `UITableViewCell` with a `UITableViewCellStyleValue2` style. And you want to set `@"Name"` as `textLabel.text` and `@"Jason"` as `detailTextLabel.text`.

---

[image: UITableView screenshot]

You have to change the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` a little bit.

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Name";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Jason";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  So do I even drag in a Table View in IB or just a Table View Cell?  Also, I can't see how you limited it to three rows?  I REALLY appreciate the help!!

Comment: Just grab one of the UITableView tutorials you can find. TableViews and its DataSource methods are a little bit too complicated to explain them in a SO answer. But there are plenty of tutorials out there and since most of them are for beginners you won't have big problems. If you have any question feel free to come back to SO and ask another question

Answer (score 1):

You can't "really" create columns in UITableView, but you can use Cell Styles to achieve a  similar effect.

You can use the UITableViewCellStyleValue1 style to achieve what you say
Here is an exemple:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

cell.textLabel.text = @"Name";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Jason";


return cell;
}
```

Here is an exemple of what it looks like:
http://blog.blackwhale.at/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/Bild-3.png

Or, but more complicated if you are new to ObjectiveC, you can create your own CellView in a XIB and use it in your code:
http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/06/28/custom-uitableviewcell-from-a-xib-in-interface-builder/

Edit: Sorry, fluchtpunkt has been faster than me ;)

Comment: Thank you ingham!  The link to the example is precisely what I'm looking for.  I'm just confused on what I need to do within Interface Builder and do I essentially repeat your sample code for each cell I'd like to add?

Comment: @Jason you should not read the custom uitableviewcell tutorial for now. Before you dig into custom cells you should play around some days with standard cells.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should add a label on the table cell, and give a border

like this :

//------------------- first column -------------------------------------------------------------------

```
UILabel * label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 312, 43)];
[label1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:18]];
[label1 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label1.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];
label1.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
label1.numberOfLines = 0;
label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",[[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"xxxxx"]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label1];
```

//------------------- second column -------------------------------------------------------------------

```
UILabel * label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(314, 0, 125, 43)];
[label2 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:18]];
[label2 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label2.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];
label2.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"xxxxxx"]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label2];
```